# Is it possible to fix boot on (probably corrupted) bitlocker+tpm encrypted win11 partition?

Tags: boot, multi-boot, windows-11, bitlocker

I have a dual-boot ubunntu+win11 setup on my drive. Out of sudden, after normal shutdown, next day neither the grub nor windows boot manager could boot. After running fsck from ubuntu live usb, ubuntu boot got fixed. But windows still cannot boot, showing blue screen with error: inaccessible boot partition. Startup repair doesn't work, nor the option to reinstall the system and keep the files.

I thought that maybe I can solve the issue with fsck too, after unlocking the win11 partition with a tool like dislocker. It didn't work though, and I've read it's not possible at all if the drive was encrypted under TPM. In the meantime I have also cleared TPM and PK keys, if that matters (I have recovery keys)

How can I fix this w/o wiping the partition?

Comment: Likely the only way is to restore from the last disk image. Also check for drive damage -- sometimes SSD failure shows up as an unwritable partition.

Comment: If "inaccessible boot device" is indeed the blue screen message, then you should
-boot win11 setup
-press shift f10 when at the language selection prompt to get to a command line
-there, use manage-bde -unlock c: -rp 1232...reckey... and after unlocking, do chkdsk /f c: